# populating form input value with existing data from firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I have a form by which an user can update their existing data.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="memberPristine.name" 
    #name="ngForm" ngControl="name">
```

Component class for this form

```
form: ControlGroup;
memberPristine: {
    name: ''
};
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) {
}

private buildForm(): void{
 this.form = this.fb.group({
     name: ['', Validators.required]
 })
} 
 ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.member$.subscribe(x=>{
      this.memberPristine = x;
   });
    this.buildForm();
  }
```

user service class

```
export class UserService {
  member$: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(a => {
      this.member$ = this.af.database.object('/members/'+a.uid);
    });
  }
```

Although member$ is a type of FirebaseObjectObservable It could not be accessed from the component class.
When I run this I got an error. 
`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.`

Comment: af or auth is not defined. How are you injecting it. I don't see it anywhere

Comment: this.userService.member$.update(member); works fine.. :(

Comment: make your constructor argument, private, `private af: AngularFire`

Comment: not working with private arg

Comment: auth is supposed to return an observable but it is not defined. Try to debug what is available in your constructor, starting with this.af, then this.af.auth. You can just use console.log() for quick debugging. Then figure out why this.af.auth is undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.af.auth().subscribe( ... );` ?

Comment: this.af.auth.subscribe(x=>{console.log(x))  logging the auth information correctly